# Recursive function for finding power returns zero for large exponents

Tags: c++, recursion

The function bellow works fine for small positive exponents and base. If the exponent is large then memory wouldn't be enough and the program should be terminated. Instead, if that function is called for large exponents, zero is returned.Why? One guess is that a multiplication with zero occurred but there is no such case.

One example where zero is returned is `power(2,64)` .

```
unsigned long long int power(unsigned long long int base,int exp){

    if (exp == 0 && base != 0)
        return 1;

    return base*power(base,exp-1);
}
```

Comment: Aside from filling memory, you should also worry about overflowing the result. `2^64` is `1<<64`, which is 1 bit above the size of a 64-bit integer, so that bit ceases to exist. In an unsigned integer, it just goes away. If it were signed, you'd have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @underscore_d that comment is better than my answer. It should be an answer.

Comment: Side note: What would happen if anyone provided base == 0??? (Hint: What is this site's name?)

Comment: 2^64 **is** zero in 64-bit modulo arithmetic.

Comment: To correct myself: As Evg pointed out elsewhere, left-shifting <= the width is undefined behaviour, for signed _or_ unsigned integers.

Comment: Note that, in addition to your oveflow problem, this code is rather inefficient

Comment: @underscore_d UB is not really relevant here, as zach is continuously shifting by less than variable width (`uint64_t x = 1; x <<= 32; x <<= 32;` is legal)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from filling memory, you should also worry about overflowing the result. 2^64 is 1<<64, which is 1 bit above the size of a 64-bit integer, so due to unsigned modulo arithmetic, that bit ceases to exist, and you end up with 0.

Not relevant in your case, as you shift by smaller amounts, but left-shifting by a number of places equal to or greater than the width of the (promoted) left operand is undefined behaviour, for either signed or unsigned (see e.g. [this link](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT34-C.+Do+not+shift+an+expression+by+a+negative+number+of+bits+or+by+greater+than+or+equal+to+the+number+of+bits+that+exist+in+the+operand) and [these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301318/recursive-function-for-finding-power-returns-zero-for-large-exponents/62301582#comment110185797_62301426)). This contrasts from overflow due to smaller shifts (or other arithmetic ops), which is well-defined as performing modulo for unsigned types but invokes UB for signed.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing [integer-overflow](/questions/tagged/integer-overflow) and that happends to hit zero at some point.

Answer (score 1):

`pow(2ULL, 64)` is equal to `(1ULL << 64)` (if `(1ULL << 64)` were defined).

It is trivial to see that if you bitshift `1ULL` 64 bits to the left there is no data left in a 64 bit `unsigned long long`. This is called `overflow`.

Comment: `1ULL << 64` as a C++ language construct is undefined behaviour (unless `1ULL` has more than 64 bits).

Comment: according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic this this is defined behavior for unsigned left side. It is only UB for signed left side.

Comment: *In any case, if the value of the right operand is negative or is greater or equal to the number of bits in the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.*